# How to return a new object using a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, parameters, numerical-methods

I'm doing an homework question:

"Each part of this question asks you to write a function that takes as a parameter one of the objects you created classes for in Q1, and does something with it. In Q2A write a method called cloneDog() that takes an object of type Dog and returns a new
Dog object with the same name and breed, but with an age of 0, and that does glow green. The original dog should remain unharmed."

I'm trying to return an object with different values in fields. I need to return the object without changing the values of the fields.

My field is:

```
public class Dog
{
    String name;
    int age;
    String breed;
    boolean glowsGreen;
}
```

My Q1A Code is:

```
Dog getTegon()
    {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog(); 
        dog1.name = "Tegon";
        dog1.age = 2;
        dog1.breed = "Beagle";
        dog1.glowsGreen = false;
        return dog1;
    }
```

For Q2A, i don't know how to use the parameter for different values:

```
Dog cloneDog(Dog getTegon)
{

    enter code here

}
```

Comment: Please stop posting external screenshots of your questions.

Comment: am I the only one who just sees a bunch of a's in lieu of post?

Comment: @vandale I fixed that

Answer (score 2):

> i don't know how to use the parameter for different values:

You just reference the values you want to copy

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog();
dog1.name = getTegon.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a copy constructor in your `Dog` class like so:

```
public Dog(Dog otherDog) {
  this.name = otherDog.name;
  this.age = otherDog.age;
  // etc..
}
```

And then call that inside `cloneDog()`